# Compare date with datetime64[ns] - Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Good evening,

I need to display which dates are between today and a given date in the past. Here is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,timedelta


df = pd.DataFrame({'DateOFBirth': ['28/03/2020','2/03/2020','12/02/2021']})
df['DateOFBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOFBirth'],format='%d/%m/%Y')

print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

x = input ("No of days: ")
today = datetime.date(datetime.now())
result = today - timedelta(days=int(x))

#np.datetime(result).astype(datetime64)
print(result < df['DateOFBirth'] < today)
```

I tried to cast date to datetime64[ns] and the other way around but I had no luck. Any solution to make the last print() statement work? Thank you!

Sample output:
If today is 28.03.2020 and x is set to 30 days the output should be:

```
28/03/2020
2/03/2020
```

Comment: Can you add a sample output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [between](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) too

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,timedelta


df = pd.DataFrame({'DateOFBirth': ['28/03/2020','2/03/2020','12/02/2021']})
df['DateOFBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOFBirth'],format='%d/%m/%Y')

x = input ("No of days: ")
today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now())
result = today - timedelta(days=int(x))
bw_values = df[df['DateOFBirth'].between(result, today, inclusive=False)]

# output if x = 30
print(bw_values)
  DateOFBirth
0  2020-03-28
1  2020-03-02
```

Or You can also use [Query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
bw_values = df.query('@result < DateOFBirth < @today')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute `today` with `pd.to_datetime()` too, to have the same date format :

```
today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now())
```

An other error may occur because you are comparing an entire column with a single number:

```
print(result < df['DateOFBirth'] < today)
```

You can compute the output you want with this line instead:

```
mask = (df['DateOFBirth'] > result) & (df['DateOFBirth'] <= today)
print(df.loc[mask])
```

The result will be:

```
    DateOFBirth
0   2020-03-28
1   2020-03-02
```

Comment: And if I would like to display the result and not the bool value, how am I suppose to do that? print(mask) returns a bool value

Comment: You can print `df.loc[mask]`